# How to show first not last image in Lightbox?

Tags: javascript, lightbox

Hello i use lightbox like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lightbox/js/lightbox.js"></script>
    <link href="lightbox/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
    </head>

<body>

<a href='http://polishwords.com.pl/images/logo179x24.png' rel="lightbox[roadtrip]"><img src="http://polishwords.com.pl/images/logo179x24.png"  /></a>      
<a href='http://polishwords.com.pl/images/logo179x24.png' rel="lightbox[roadtrip]"><img src="http://polishwords.com.pl/images/logo179x24.png"  /></a>
<a href='http://polishwords.com.pl/images/logo179x24.png' rel="lightbox[roadtrip]"><img src="http://polishwords.com.pl/images/logo179x24.png"  /></a>


</body>

</html>
```

Live demo: http://polishwords.com.pl/grono/fb_dragchallenge2/test.html

And when i click any image it shows gallery but with image 3/3 not image 1/3. 
How to show first image not the last one?

I use this: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: Show us your code, or the simpler answer, just reverse your order of images to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Sorry, i've put it. I've reversed the images, and now, when i click the link i am shown the image i desire, but below there is written: image 3 of 3 and to see other images i need to click prev, and this is not desired, because it should show 1/3 and next button...

Comment: I actually upvoted you, others downvoted you probably because that question was too vague.

Comment: I don't typically downvote anything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in the newest version of Lightbox from the link above. I've changed to other software.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting them in a group like so:

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]">image #1</a>
<a href="images/image-2.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]">image #2</a>
<a href="images/image-3.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]">image #3</a>
```

Comment: Hello, thx for answer, i've tried it and still th  same result :(

Comment: Try making a demo page to just use the images, the jquery, the css to try and get it working standalone.  If it works, you know the problem is with the page.  If it doesn't work, there may be a bug in the lightbox and you may want to use another one.

Comment: i've made the demo see above pls.

Comment: This seems like a bug, so I recommend trying to download the latest version and try again.  If you can't get it to work, we can try to change your javascript, but you may find it more beneficial to just contact the developer since this seems like an active project he would better help you, plus if it is a bug, he will fix it which will help other people, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in function `Lightbox.prototype.start` (lightbox.js). After it adds pictures into the album, variable `imageNumber` still contains the number of the last image.

Change `imageNumber` to `0` before the `this.changeImage` function call:

```
imageNumber = 0; // insert this line before 
this.changeImage(imageNumber);
```

Comment: It's right, but not working in a set of images if you click in specific image. It will always open the FIRST image. I solved, will post a solution

Answer (score 0):

I have solved in this way:

If you have to open lightbox from an external button, add an optional button's attribute like data-first="1". (eg: `data-lightbox="gallery1" data-first="1"`)

in lightbox.js add this code BEFORE THIS LINE: `this.changeImage(imageNumber);`

```
if ($link.attr("data-first") == "1") imageNumber = 0;
```

If you don't set this attribute, lightbox will open in the selected image (if you have a set of images in html page)